# Роутер режет скорость

Tags: wifi

*Прошу прощения если обратился не на тот ресурс сети StackOverflow, если это так прошу оповестить меня об этом с просьбой закрыть вопрос.*

Провайдер выдает 1 гигабит, но роутер раздает даже не полных 54Мбит. ([Результат теста](http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/6099780438)) Общался с консультантом провайдера, определили что напрямую от кабеля идет все верно, так как и напрямую(по кабелю от роутера) идет так же максимум. Тем не менее по Wi-Fi идет только "теоретических 100Мбит", что видно по тесту выше.

В компьютер встроен адаптер TP-Link модели [TL-WN722N](http://www.tp-link.ua/ru/products/details/TL-WN722N.html) на 150Мбит, поддерживающий 802.11n и работающий в этом режиме с этим роутером(по крайней мере так говорит приложение, через которое он работает). Роутер настроен на режимы 11bgn mixed.

Гигабитный роутер TP-Link модели [TL-WR1043ND V4](http://www.tp-link.ua/ru/products/details/TL-WR1043ND.html). Был обновлен до последней прошивки с [официального сайта](http://www.tp-link.ua/ru/download/TL-WR1043ND_V4.html#Firmware). Раздавать он теоретически должен все 300 Мбит, но похоже он раздает примерно 100. Роутер автоматически определил канал, который в действительности имеет меньше всего помех.

Так же я знаю что роутер в любом случае будет резать скорость, но тут суть в том что после смены тарифа с 100 Мбит до 1Гбит скорость не изменилась, а должна была вырасти (вновь теоретически) в 10 раз. Может я что-то упустил, что еще может помешать принимать полные 150-300Мбит?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54791/discussion-on-question-by-levelleor---).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем я немного разобрался в своей проблеме. Благодаря комментаторам в большей мере, в меньшей мере удачным запросам в поисковиках. Почти уверен что проблема заключается в крайне густом расположении роутеров в округе. Их около 70-ти, что достает мой приемник и 95% из них работают на той же частоте что и мой.

5 роутеров с крайне высоким качеством сигнала пересекаются каналом с моим, что явно и мешает по большей мере. Я так понимаю нужно стараться как-то уменьшить это "загрязнение" роутерами, уменьшая их количество, договариваясь с соседями, но не думаю что это очень хорошая идея.

Варианты решения в этом случае: купить роутер на 5ГГц, использовать Lan порты роутера для связи напрямую или использовать кабель провайдера прямиком компьютером.

Не проанализировав этот вопрос подробнее я даже не задумывался о покупке 5ГГц роутеров, хотя есть модели по примерно той же цене...